# Edit The Src Of a Image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

**HTML Code**

```
<img class="blog-picture ul-normal-classic" src="https://example.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/example300-300x203.jpg" alt="Beintehaa300">
```

**Whta I Need:**

```
<img class="blog-picture ul-normal-classic" src="https://example.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/example300.jpg" alt="Beintehaa300">
```

I just want to remove (-300x203) from the src.
Is this possible using js or PHP or any other language I want to implement this code in WordPress?

Comment: You should paste the PHP code that generate that. It is possibile inside wordpress to just specify image size to get what you need but we need to see the piece of code that is responsable for that output

Comment: I made a simple post through wordpress and then I gave it a category after that in elementor I call that category So some images were crop by default and some are fine.

Comment: Please share more details. Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - this question is most probably not related to **all** of the tagged technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var allImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
        var imageSource = allImages[i].getAttribute('src');

        if (imageSource.includes('-300x203')) {
            var replacedSource = allImages[i].getAttribute('src').replace('-300x203', '');
            allImages[i].setAttribute('src', replacedSource);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Put this script on page

Comment: I have more then one hundred picture so Please suggest me a function which can remove (-300x203)  from the images

Comment: ok I have edited the answer as you asked.

Comment: Well your work is great but It work locally not on the server

Comment: this is because WordPress take time to load on server as compared to local, you can use "setTimeout" function and add delay by 2 seconds. Or did you find any other error on console?? If it is possible, please share your website link.

Answer (score 1):

use preg replace, assuming that your image alwsays be same thumbnail, looks like current one has 300px width set, and height on auto you cna use

```
$content = '<img class="blog-picture ul-normal-classic" src="https://example.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/example300-300x203.jpg" alt="Beintehaa300">';
$content = preg_replace('/-300x*[0-9][0-9][0-9]./', '.', $content);
echo $content;
```

if you want it to work with any tumbnail sizes (and get full image url) you cna mobify it to

```
$content = preg_replace('/-*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x*[0-9][0-9][0-9]./', '.', $content);
```